# Regex: Matching character set specific number of times

Tags: c#, regex, notepad++

Ok so this is likely a ridiculously stupid question but I can't seem to find a workable answer so please forgive my ignorance if the answer is obvious. All I would like is a Regex which will match a hex value exactly 8 times. So I've tried something like this:

**My Regex:**

```
 [0-9a-fA-F]{8}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
 D651000000060D60FADF0DFCE080E020636263633534623231386339
```

**Sample Failing Input (where my given regex matches when I don't want it to):**

```
 ........@%........$dc073bcc-6aa5
```

Yet for some reason this wont work for me. From what I understand the `{8}` should match the preceding regex 8 times...yet this doesn't seem to work in either C# or notepad++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of a "hex value"?

Comment: A character, 0-F (or f since I don't care about casing)

Comment: Think of the regex I want as matching a byte, as represented through an ascii string.

Comment: "A character, 0-F" - your regex *does* match 8 hex digits anywhere in the text. "Think of the regex I want as matching a byte" - a byte is represented by *two* hex digits, isn't it?

Comment: Right, typed without thinking. 8 hexadecimal digits. But thats beside the point of the question, 8 characters who are either 0-9, a-f, or A-F

Comment: With this sample data your Regex expression would yield seven matches of 8 characters length each.

Comment: Then, again, your regex matches exactly what you want :)

Comment: Ah, the problem I think is that I get matches when I dont want them...I want to limit the length of the string to be of size 8. Turns out I needed the start\end of string anchors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is slightly confusing as to if you want 6 hex characters, 8 times:

`([0-9a-fA-F]{6}){8}`

Or an 8 digit hex character:

`[0-9a-fA-F]{8}` or `[0-9a-fA-F]{4,8}`  if you dont want to require 8 characters.

I would recommend testing on:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

If these don't get it, can you post a sample of the values you're trying to match (note that if you have these on multiple lines in notepad++ you also need to be looking for the newline characters)

Comment: I ended up needing the start\end anchors so match per string I was iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

A more straight forward answer! The **character set** I will use in these examples are *all digits from 0 to 9*, just for simplicity.

- **Match all digits, 8 times:** `[0-9]{8}`
- **Match all digits, 8 or more times:** `[0-9]{8}[0-9]*` (first match 8 times, then match any number of times)

You can test here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: you can just do `[0-9]{8,}` instead of `[0-9]{8}[0-9]*`.